Show Facebook group posts in date range?
Is there any trick to show Facebook group posts using a custom date range without using the search bar (because it's useless)
The infinite scrolling is the stupdiest idea ever made...
Please I need a solution or a trick...
Can I find a browser extension or something like that forDate Range extension to display Facebook posts from a specific date period example?
Thanks everybody.
